# Add JS functionalities to a nodejs express app (slideshow)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to nodejs and I am working on a milestone project. I am using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB. I had vanilla JS code that was retrieving dummy data and manipulating the HTML through the DOM. I understand I cannot use DOM through an express app. Where would I begin to do the same thing with express? I want to retrieve data from mongoDB and when I click a button on my html retrieve post[i].title and post[i].content

```
function currentPost(n) {

    post1= '<div class="blogPost"><a href="post1.html"><h3 class="resize">
Post 1</h3></a><p class="resize">    "Lorem ipsum dolor"</p></div>';    

if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("containerBlogPost").innerHTML = post1;    
}
else if (n == 1){
    document.getElementById("containerBlogPost").innerHTML = post2;    

}
else if (n == 2){
    document.getElementById("containerBlogPost").innerHTML = post3;    

}
else if (n == 3){
    document.getElementById("containerBlogPost").innerHTML = post4;    

}
}
```

On an event I was using that data to upload my html using the DOM. I don't need ridiculous details but I need guidance. I have been struggling with this all day.

Comment: You should look into [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Use it to pull the data from your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client-side JavaScript, you would need to send a request to the Express server for data. The easiest way to do this is to make the button a part of a form and have the form send a GET request to the server. The Express server would have a route to handle GET requests that would query the database, and send the response from the database to the client. The client-side JavaScript would then pick out the data from the response, and you can populate the innerHTML of elements with the data.

In order to do this, another helpful thing to look up would be callbacks so your client-side code doesn't populate the page before the response from the server comes in.

Learn more about sending data with forms from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).
Learn more about Express route handling [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).